# django m2m form is not saving although using form.save_m2m()

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I have manyToMany relationship with two models: researcher and program.

```
class Program(BaseModel):
researcher = models.ManyToManyField('researcher.Researcher',blank=True ,verbose_name=_('Researchers'))
```

I was trying to add some researchers to the program so that's what I did:

```
self.object = form.save(commit=False)
researchers=[]
        for uuid in researchers_uuid:
            researcher=Researcher.objects.get(uuid=uuid)
            researchers.append(researcher)
        self.object.bounty_type = bounty
        self.object.researcher.set(researchers)
        logger.info(self.object.researcher.all()) ## => 1
        self.object.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        logger.info(self.object.researcher.all()) ## => 2
```

The first logger gives me all the researchers, while the other one give me an empty QuertSet
so, how can I save a m2m relationship? and what's wrong in my code.

Comment: Can you please share the entire view?

Comment: @SunderamDubey 
It's more than 130 Line so i can't share it here in the post
but it's an update view to update a model called program
everything is working fine and everything is updated successfully, but the "Program.researcher" doesn't get updated